# Objective-C productivity question deleted too hastily

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, vote-to-undelete

[*How to be more productive in Objective C*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24877091/643383) was just closed and deleted within an hour of being posted. That's understandable -- there were a number of things wrong with it: the tone was somewhat whiny, the title didn't accurately reflect the intent of the question, and the useful part of the question was somewhat buried. I almost voted to close it myself until I re-read and found that there is, in fact, a pretty good question hidden in there.

I've since edited the question to remove some of the extraneous stuff, improve the title, and get to the point. I think it's worth undeleting and reopening this one -- it's a question that could really help others who are new to Objective-C and the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Please take a look and vote to undelete and reopen if you agree.

Here's a screenshot including my edits for lower-rep users:

[image: screenshot for lower-rep users]

Comment: Screenshot by a chance for less than 10k users?

Comment: Good idea, @SantaClaus. Done.

Comment: Hmmmm. I may be too critical, but it still seems a bit unclear and could use a bit of formatting. (Ex. Putting "UIViewController" in code spans using backticks). As it stands it's basically. a block of text.

Comment: That should not have been deleted as quickly as it was. I've undeleted this, although I'll let others vote on whether it should be reopened in its edited state. It should have at least been given a chance to be edited and improved during the "on hold" period. It wasn't blatantly off topic or otherwise unsalvageable.

Comment: @SantaClaus "unclear" is grounds for "closed for improvement" not "kill with fire" (aka "delete"). Isn't the criteria for closing vs deleting "I can see this becoming a good question following some refinement"? I definitely can see good question potential here, but this is admittedly subjective.